# Is the order of selection parameters important?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If i use a table containing at least 2 columns like this :

```
[User]
[FirstName]|[LastName]
Robert-Dupont
Louis-Dupont
Georges-Andre
```

Assuming that there is a huge amount of data and that there is much more unique result in 'FirstName' than in 'LastName', which query is the fastest :

Query 1 :

```
SELECT * USER WHERE LastName = 'Dupont' AND FirstName = 'Robert'
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * USER WHERE FirstName = 'Robert' AND LastName = 'Dupont'
```

Is there a difference ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: no. different at all

Comment: Order of evaluation is neither guaranteed nor respected (except for the CASE expression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the comparisons does not matter.  SQL Server should optimize the `WHERE` clause for the data.

However, if you care about performance, you should use an index, either `user(firstname, lastname)` or `user(lastname, firstname)`.  The order of comparisons is not the right thing to be thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

an index of below form

```
(firstname,lastname)
```

Can help in both the queries..

```
firstname='' and lastname=''
```

or

```
lastname='' and fastname=''
```

so your both queries are faster,but when you issue query of below form ,with same index

```
firstname>='' and lastname=''
```

Firstname uses index and SQLServer can't use index on second column ,but it uses residual lookup to filter out values

Answer (score 0):

Both query are same faster. Because  'where' clause includes conditions. That is not important unique columns .

Comment: Can you try to clarify this answer. I can't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: The WHERE clause is used to extract only those records that fulfill a specified criterion.  So it does not matter that the you have unique column. Two conditions have same significance.    (Asked :  _that there is much more unique result in 'FirstName' than in 'LastName_)

Answer (score 0):

it's exactly the same when both are on the same level. but this is definitely better:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM USER
         WHERE LastName = 'Dupont')
 WHERE FirstName = 'Robert'
```

**EDIT**

Going back to Relational Algebra, it's better to filter any results as far down the tree as possible. Assuming that last names are rarer than first names, you 1st filter the 'Duponts' and then look for the 'Roberts' in the result set.

Comment: Can you explain how this is better? This isn't going to do anything but make the query more difficult to read for humans.

Comment: @SeanLange - I have edited my answer to explain the logic but I strongly disagree with you. Inner queries are not more difficult to read if formatted properly.

Comment: But in this case it isn't going to provide any actual benefit for performance. It adds more characters and more complex to read for the same result. I understand your logic but in sql server the execution plan is going to be the exact same thing.

Comment: @SeanLange - yes, in this particular example it may not make much of a difference. but it will in every real-world scenario. in any case Sql Server will not be able to make a logical decision as to which column is better to be filtered first.

Comment: If you can provide a solid example where this type of query produces a more efficient execution plan I would like to see it. I have seen this type of thing brought up before and I have never seen an example where it provided any benefit to performance.

Comment: @Ted - I believe this is where Statistics kicks in so SQL server should be able to come with a suitable execution plan.
I do agree that it's not always best and sometime you need to give it some hints but I consider it to be a last resort.
In this particular case, I don't even think this will impact the query plan  as it is a single table query.